# mysql insert where data from combine two table with no relation

Tags: mysql

I have two table 
Table1

```
NO | CITY  
1  | city1 
2  | city2
```

Table2

```
NO | PRODUCT  | CODE
1  | product1 | 1
2  | product2 | 2
3  | product3 | 1
```

and I want to combine table1 and table2 where table2 code is 1 and insert it into table3 like this
Table3

```
NO | CITY  | PRODUCT
1  | city1 | product1
2  | city1 | product3
3  | city2 | product1
4  | city2 | product3
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What's the logic of your expect reuslt? why don't you get `product2 `

Comment: because I only want to use PRODUCT from Table2 where CODE is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `NO` is the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, we can try to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`
with `CROSS JOIN` to do that.

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (CITY  ,PRODUCT)
SELECT t1.CITY  ,t2.PRODUCT
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
WHERE t2.CODE = 1
```